# Basic questions about LEMP and Reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am planning to set up a LEMP server and run a Wordpress site and I also want to add reverse proxy to the server. My question is where do I get started?

Should I set up the LEMP server first and add the proxy server later on?

Should I use Ubuntu or other platforms?

What should I use for the reverse proxy?

The reverse proxy is suppose to hide the real ip address of the server, so what is the best way to choose the IP address for the reverse proxy?

I have read, in a LAMP server I could use Nginx as the reverse proxy, but what about the LEMP server, can I still use NGINX as the reverse proxy?

I am so confused and do not know where to get started. I will be grateful If someone can kindly clarify the steps involved in setting up a LEMP server with a reverse proxy. Any links and tutorials is also welcomed.

Thank you

Comment: If you don't know how you should not do that in the first place.

Comment: I am here to learn.

Comment: The reverse proxy goes last, isn't that obvious? What use would be a reverse proxy if it wouldn't have nothing to forward. Use whichever you like, it does not matter, usually it's nginx / haproxy (generic load balancer). If you are after a professional webserver, don't install Ubuntu lol, go for CentOS. Anyway this question is too broad. Come back again and ask when you have a specific problem to solve.

Comment: The second comment is better than the first one.